# Adding intent to images to link to another page

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-imageview

I need help with my shopping application favourites page. It is a gridview layout with images saved for illustration purposes. I require those images to be able to intent to each of their different product page and not all to the same page. Here are some code snippets of my sample.

Favourites.java:

```
public class Favourites extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageView btnAllShops, btnFavourites, btnUploads, btnSettings, btnBuys;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favourites);

    GridView gvFavourites = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvFavourites);
    gvFavourites.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gvFavourites.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(Favourites.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
            // start one activity
            break;
            case 1:
            // start another activity
            break;
            // etc.

        }
        }});
}

private void findViewById() {
    btnAllShops = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnAllShops);
    btnFavourites = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnFavourites);
    btnUploads = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnUploads);
    btnSettings = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnSettings);
    btnBuys = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnBuys);

    btnAllShops.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnFavourites.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnUploads.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSettings.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnBuys.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnAllShops:
        Intent iA = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllShops.class);
        startActivity(iA);
        break;

    case R.id.btnFavourites:
        Intent iF = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Favourites.class);
        startActivity(iF);

        break;

    case R.id.btnUploads:
        Intent iU = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Uploads.class);
        startActivity(iU);

        break;

    case R.id.btnSettings:
        Intent iS = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(iS);

        break;

    case R.id.btnBuys:
        Intent iBuy = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Buys.class);
        startActivity(iBuy);

        break;
    }
}

}
```

ImageAdapter.java:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(266, 266));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}
// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};

}
```

Comment: I think you should use `setOnClickListener` for each image in the gridview.

Comment: Can you explain your problem little bit.

Comment: @Miguel Rivera I will try.

Comment: @keshav i want each of my images to be able to intent to each of their own page, instead of all going into the same page.

Comment: you have to create a different activity for each item.

Comment: @MiguelRivera I have more than 10 images, do i have to create a activity for each of them?

Comment: well that's the first thing that comes in my mind. another is to put the things to display in a db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an onClickListener inside the getView method of your imageAdapter. For example.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ImageView imageView;
if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
    imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(266, 266));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
} else {
    imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
}

imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
//add your listener here.
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (position) {
            //put whatever your different positions are
            case 0:
                startActivity(whatever activity name);
                break;
            case 1:
                startActivity(next activity name);
                break;
            //etc...
        startActivity("whatever you need to start");
    }
}

return imageView;
```

}

Comment: does the onClickListener apply to 1 image or all the images? Thanks!

Comment: I should've specified, but if you want each image to link to something else, put a switch on your position integer, then depending on which one that is, start some activity.

Comment: Is it possible to show me how you do that? Sorry to trouble you.

Comment: Sure I'll add another answer with that in it.

Comment: So different images have to have different activity for it? What if i have more than 10 images?

Comment: It depends. Will the page be completely different or practically the same but with a few changes? If it's the same you could do what the other guy said, pass in the position in the intent.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It would be completely different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is add a tag in your image view. in your code after this line

```
 imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
```

like

```
imageView.setTag....
```

then in onclick() you can get this tag and you can pass the id in intent.

NOTE : you can set id of your resource in tag

Comment: is it possible to show me how you do that? still quite new to it.